# Way of estimating the parameters of a distribution that encourages samples not to try to game the system?

Tags: distributions, estimation, estimators, voting-system, adversarial-example

There is a distribution $D(\theta)$, where $\theta$ represents the parameters of the distribution. To sample from the distribution, a bunch of people are called to give their samples $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. Given those samples, one can estimate $\theta$, and we'll all be on our merry way.

However, a lot rides on what $\theta$ ends up being. So while person $i$'s true sample is $x_i$, he wants $\theta$ to be estimated to be $\theta_i$ (his preference), and he has reason to believe that $\tilde{\theta}_i$ will be what the ultimate estimate ends up being. So he strategically says that his sample is $\tilde{x}_i$, instead of the $x_i$ he truly believes it to be.

The simplest example would be a friend that once told me that, if they see the rating of a movie lower than they'd like, they rate it a 10 (to get the average closer to the value they want). And vice versa (rating a movie a 0 to lower the rating to what they truly believe). I'm not sure there's any decent mathematical methods to prevent my friend's psychopathic behavior, but in certain cases, I wonder if there actually might be hope.

Namely, I want an estimator (not necessarily maximum likelihood) that prevents people from trying to game it (i.e. $\tilde{x}_i = x_i$ no matter what $\theta_i$ and $\tilde{\theta}_i$ are).

And the particular example I had in mind as I came up with this question was for the Dirichlet distribution $D(\alpha)$. A bunch of people want to decide how to allocate a finite resource (e.g. water) across $K$ places. But each person has their ideal distribution $p_i$, what they think the ultimate distribution will end up being $\tilde{\alpha}_i$, and the thing they say $\tilde{p}_i$ to get the final answer closer to their ideal. Is there any way to estimate $\alpha$ so that people don't feel incentivized to lie about their true feelings to game the system?

My hunch is "no", as [a lot of voting theory proves that a perfect un-gameable voting system doesn't exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbard%27s_theorem). That being said, there are "better" voting systems that are "less gameable", and so I was hoping for a better estimator that was less gameable.

If there's no clear answer, I'd also like to know if there are any research buzzwords that are relevant to this.

Answer (score 0):

So first off, you are right. It might be worthwhile to think of this within a general frame work of mechanism design and then tweak elements as you would like. With that being said, I think you can set this up as a mechanism design problem, in particular you can find try to find a Vickrey Clarke Grove Mechanism for your problem. Which is closely related to the voting games that you have described above. I will provide a general framework and then you can Google around it or I can answer questions as you go.

First some notation, let $\theta_i$ be any report by the agent and let $\theta^t$ be the truthful report. Any set of reports can be given by $\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2,\dots, \theta_n)$. Now let us do the following:

1. Ask agent to report their value function for any combination of ratings $v_i(\theta)$. This basically asks the agent to report how they feel about *any* combination of ratings.
2. Based on the above, it finds out $\theta^*$ such that :$$\theta^g = argmax_{\theta\in \Theta} \sum_{i=1}^N v_i(\theta)$$ This finds out the combination of reports that maximizes everyone's welfare, given the report of agent $i$. Thus $\theta^g$ is the *gamed* rating.
3. Pay agent $i$ the sum of everyone else's valuation of this gamed rating plus some function (of our choosing and defined in step 4) of everyone else's valuation, $$p_i := \sum_{j\neq i} v_j(\theta^g) + h_j(v_{-i})$$
4. Ask agent $i$ to pay a price for being *asked* to rate. Think of this as the price you have to pay because your rating affects everyone else. $$h_j (v_{-i}) = \max_{\theta\in\Theta} \sum_{j\neq i}v_j(\theta)$$
   Lets say the value that maximizes this is $\theta^{g^{-i}}$, then $h_j$ becomes,
   $$h_j(v_{-i}) = \sum_{j\neq i} v_j(\theta^{g^{-i}})$$.

Bringing all this together we have the final payment by an agent $i$ to be :
$$p_i = \sum_{j\neq i} v_j(\theta^g) - \sum_{j\neq i} v_j(\theta^{g^{-i}})$$
Which is the difference between the social welfare of the gamified rating when the agent $i$ is present and the gamified rating when agent $i$ is not present. This can be interpreted to mean that the agent should pay the *distortion* they cause by being present in the system.
All this to say, I think you should find out how a sample would *pay* for not lying. If the payment mechanism is truthful and optimal (everyone is incentivized to tell the truth and the societally best rating is achieved)

To get more specific, we can define the utility function of any one agent as follows, where the agent lies by declaring $\theta'_i$:
$$v_i(\theta_i',\theta_{-i}) = (\theta_i - \frac{1}{n}\theta_i'-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j \neq i}\theta_j)^2$$

Then the "gamified" rating $\theta^g = \frac{1}{n}(\theta'_i + \sum_{j\neq i} \theta_j)$

hence the VCG payment is :
$$p_i = \sum_{j\neq i} v_j(\theta'_i,\theta_{-i})  - \sum_{j\neq i} v_j(\theta_j)$$
$$p_i = \sum_{j\neq i} (\frac{1}{n} (\theta'_i +\sum_{-i} \theta_j)-\theta_j)^2 - \sum_{j\neq i} (\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{-i}\theta_j-\theta_j)^2$$
Where the first term is the welfare of everyone else, other than $i$ with $i$ having lied and the second term is the welfare of everyone else had $i$ not been present.